# Dual-booting Windows 10: Shared drive no longer accessible

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-10

I have a setup as such:

1 x 256GB SSD - Ubuntu 16.04

1 x 256GB SSD - Windows 10

1 x 1TB HDD - Shared for both

I was able to access the shared drive from Ubuntu with no issues, but all of a sudden, if I try to go into it Ubuntu will say:

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/user/B450A12E50A0F86E: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" "/dev/sdb1" "/media/user/B450A12E50A0F86E"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb1': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

Exactly what did Windows do? I barely use it; I think I've booted it twice or so since installing this setup, but certainly I've booted it, then back into Ubuntu, and still had access to the shared drive. What caused this? Can I regain access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this command :

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb1
```

Comment: That worked, thank you. Can you explain what caused this so I can avoid it in the future?

Comment: https://itsfoss.com/solve-ntfs-mount-problem-ubuntu-windows-8-dual-boot/